# When a Youtube Brand Channel links back to the brand's website, must the links be tagged?

Tags: google-analytics

Typically, when sending traffic to links from an external website, we add Google Analytics parameters to the query string- "utm_campaign" and so forth. But when it's an "internal" link from another domain also owned by us, and on the same Google Analytics profile, we use the "cross-domain linking" method to maintain the session cookies across domains.

So, I'm a bit unclear about which, if either, method should be used on a YouTube Brand Channel, when linking to pages on our own site. The fact that the YouTube Brand Channel has GA on it (using the same profile) would seem to indicate that we should use the "cross-domain linking" method, but I don't think this is even a possibility, as YouTube obviously won't let us make Javascript calls on the page whenever we choose...

So, what's the appropriate way so that we can ensure that we measure which links from the YouTube brand channel to our website were clicked, led to conversion, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar what the YouTube brand-channels allows for when it comes to customizing the tracking code, and tracking code with links. But if you're allowed to use SetAllowLinker (together with setDomain, which could be set to none if you wish) and add the linker to specific links that should carry over the cookie data to your regular profile. This means it wont show up as two specific visits when they leave the YouTube channel.

Heres a good guide I found which helps you set this up. It also includes a quick method to automatically add the linker to links, instead of manually having to add them to specific links:
http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/google-analytics-cross-domain-tracking-made-easy-14596